# Is there any way to exclude the asm function from compiling?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a source similar to this:

```
...
void func1 (uint8* p1) {
    ...
}

asm void asm_func (uint8* p_asm) {

    //asm code here
}

void func2 (uint8* p2) {
    ...
}
...
```

Is there any way to exclude the asm function from compiling ?

**The real scenario of this question:**

A developer team write code using a compiler which allow this asm syntax, a tester team is using another compiler to test the code
which not allow this asm syntax.

Tester team is not allowed to modify the source code so they cannot comment the invalid syntax code.

Tester team uses Visual Studio.

Comment: "Tester team is not allowed to modify the source code" : there is nothing you can do in this case. The tester team should prabably report that the code will not compile.

Comment: Will `asm_func` be *called* by the testers environment? If you "exclude" it then you will get build errors if you ever call it. Besides, to have different codes used by developers and testers is really not a great idea.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the `asm_func` in this case is not called in this source, and our scope is unit so we just need to test this source. I agreed with you that we will get errors if the `asm_func` is called and have different codes used by developers and testers is bad idea. But there are always some bad rules that we need to live with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, with such code you cannot do what you want.

All C compilers allow for conditional compilation... provided it is explicit in original code.

You **must** be able to either skip the whole functions using asm, or if it make sense just skip asm code:

Skip whole functions

```
...
#ifndef SKIP_ASM
asm void asm_func (uint8* p_asm) {

    //asm code here
}
#endif
...
```

Just skip asm code:

```
#ifdef SKIP_ASM
#define asm
#endif
...
asm void asm_func (uint8* p_asm) {

#ifndef SKIP_ASM
    //asm code here
#endif
}
...
```

TL/DR: the developper team **must** provide conditional compilation in the original code, or you **must** use a compiler accepting same asm syntax in the tester team.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [conditional compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) using the preprocessor. If a macro is set then define the function.

Something like

```
#ifdef HAVE_ASM_SUPPORT
asm void asm_func (uint8* p_asm) {

    //asm code here
}
#endif
```

In the developer environment you have `HAVE_ASM_SUPPORT` defined, while the testers will not have it and the function will simply not exist for the compiler.

Comment: it just remove the `asm` keywork, I have the asm code in the function. Could you please check the question again ?  I have edited.

Comment: @IlDivinCodino Updated my answer. Same solution, just a little change when and where to use conditional compilation.

Comment: Compilers typically have a way to specify #defines on the command line. So have the developers add a way to disable the assembly and then add it to the build command line when needed.

Comment: @IlDivinCodino Then it's unfortunately not possible. There's another possibility, but that also involves modifying the code, and that is to move all `asm` functions to a separate source file that is not included in the testers project.

Answer (score 0):

In your visual studio IDE settings add a pre-processor directive like below:

`asm   <blank>`. The per-processor will  replace asm statement with blank.

In this way you dont need to modify source code at all.

Note: This will work only if msvc is able to run `void asm_func (uint8* p_asm)`.

**Edit:**

As you want to skip whole function,here is the hack:

1. Ask your developers to move all the `asm` functions at bottom of source file.
2. Add a pre-processor `asm   /*`
3. Make sure that source file ends with `/***EOF**/`

P.S. I am not sure how functionality wont be affected if you dont execute these functions.

Comment: there is asm code in the function, please check my question again, I've edited. Your way just remove `asm` keyword.